# From probability theory to group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions, permutations

In the book of Shoup, Victor, ``A computational introduction to number theory and Algebra", the following theorem is presented in chapter $8$.

$\textbf{Theorem 8.13:}$. Suppose that $G$ is a finite abelian group, and that $W$ is a random variable uniformly distributed over $G$. Let $Z$ be another random variable, taking values in some finite set $U$, and suppose that $W$ and $Z$ are independent. Let $\sigma: U → G$ be some function, and define $Y := W + \sigma(Z)$. Then $Y$ is uniformly distributed over $G$, and $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

Does this theorem only holds for abelian groups, because it seems to be too strict as a conclusion for me? Could someone give a proof or example or whatever? In the book it is not exactly clear for me.

I cite here the proof

Consider any fixed values $t\in G$ and $u\in U$. Evidently, the events because $W$ and $Z$ are independent, we have $(Y = t) ∩ (Z = u)$ and $(W = t − σ(u)) ∩ (Z = u)$ are the same, and therefore,
$$P[(Y = t) ∩ (Z = u)] = P[W = t − σ(u)] P[Z = u] =\frac{1}{|G|}P[Z = u],\quad\text{$(8.16)$}$$

Since this holds for every $u\in U$, making use of total probability $P[A] =
\sum_{i\in I}P[A ∩ B_i]$, we have

$$P[Y = t] =
\sum_{u\in U}P[(Y = t) ∩ (Z = u)] = 1 P[Z = u] = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{u\in U}P[Z = u]=\frac{1}{|G|}$$

Thus, $Y$ is uniformly distributed over $G$, and by $(8.16)$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

Comment: Why downvoting such a question ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I have no idea...

Comment: It holds for any group, and indeed any quasigroup (latin square).

Comment: @SeanEberhard thank you very much. So, we can truly re-state the theorem, saying that: ``Suppose that G is a finite (abelian) group..." We do not need to restrict the theorem only for abelian Groups.

Comment: Your question could use a little more context. You wrote "In the book it is not exactly clear for me". Does the book have a proof? Does the proof actually use the "abelian" hypothesis somewhere?

Comment: @LeeMosher I cite the proof here as well as in the question above

Consider any fixed values $t\in G$ and $u\in U$. Evidently, the events because $W$ and $Z$ are independent, we have $(Y = t) ∩ (Z = u)$ and $(W = t − σ(u)) ∩ (Z = u)$ are the same, and therefore,
$$PP[(Y = t) ∩ (Z = u)] = P[W = t − σ(u)] P[Z = u] =\frac{1}{|G|}P[Z = u],\quad\text{$(8.16)$}$$

Since this holds for every $u\in U$, making use of total probability $P[A] =
\sum_{i\in I}P[A ∩ B_i]$, we have

Comment: $$P[Y = t] =
\sum_{u\in U}P[(Y = t) ∩ (Z = u)] = 1 P[Z = u] = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{u\in U}P[Z = u]=\frac{1}{|G|}$$

Thus, $Y$ is uniformly distributed over $G$, and by $(8.16)$, $Y$ and $Z$ are independent.

Comment: I do not see the abelian Hypothesis anywhere in the proof of the theorem, which seems to me that it is not a basic argument to prove the theorem. So the groups $G$, $W$ and $Y$ need not be only abelian...